# Text to the right of an image

Tags: css

I'm trying to display text to the right of an image. For some reason, if the text is short, it displays correctly. However, if I place several sentences in the text, it displays below the image.

Here's an example of what's happening: https://jsfiddle.net/deadendstreet/t0rtdu7c/

Here's the css I'm using.

```
.float-my-children > * {
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
}
.clearfix {
*zoom:1 /* for IE */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your text is in a `<div>` element, which by default is `display: block`. **[Block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)** by default have a **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** of `100%`, so attempt to 'separate' themselves out and take up a full line.

As such, what you need to do is specify a `width` for both your text and image that, when combined, **totals** `100%` (after compensating for the margins). In my example I've used **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** to compensate for **[`margin-right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-right)**.

Also note that you probably don't want to give the `margin-right` to the text (as it's the final sibling), so I've only applied it to the image in my example. If you want to increase the distance from the box, it would be more beneficial to add [**`padding`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) to the box itself.

```css
/* tell the container's children to float left: */

.float-my-children>* {
  float: left;
  
}

.float-my-children > img {
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: calc(10% - 5px);
}

.float-my-children > div {
  width: 90%;
}

/* this is called a clearfix. it makes sure that the container's children floats are cleared, without using extra markup */

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1/* for IE */
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}


/* end clearfix*/


/* below is just to make things easier to see, not required */

body>div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix float-my-children">
  <img src="http://www.carleybakker.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/tonya_testimonial.png" width=50px>
  <div>“Carley’s presentation was engaging and informative. She is a strong speaker and gave the audience valuable insights.”
    <div style="font-size: 9px">-- Board of Trade</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix float-my-children">
  <img src="http://www.carleybakker.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/tonya_testimonial.png" width=50>
  <div>Carley’s presentation was engaging and informative.</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)